# ASP.NET 6 MVC Filter by enum passed into controller action from enum select list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, enums

I have a select list in my view based on an enum. I can pass the value chosen in the select list to the controller action ok, but am having difficulty filtering on that enum value.

In other words. I have a list of posts in a blog that have a ready status. I just want to filter the posts by the ready status.

The thing is, the readyStatus property in the post model records the index of the enum, not its value. For example, the "Production Ready" value in the enum, is recorded with the value of "2", which is its index.

So I've been playing with a few options.

1.)Get the index value from the select list that will be passed into the controller action.

2.) Convert the select list value(string), for example "ProductionReady" and find its corresponding index in the enum list, then filter by that.

In the logic in the controller action, I am trying to compare the passed in value from the select list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Relevant code below

Post model

```
public ReadyStatus ReadyStatus { get; set; }
```

Enum

```
    public enum ReadyStatus
    {
        Incomplete,
        PreviewReady,
        ProductionReady
    }
```

Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> IndexFilter(string? readyStatus)
        {
            
            var posts = new List<Post>();
            if (readyStatus is null)
            {
                posts = await _context.Posts
                .Include(p => p.Blog)
                .Include(p => p.BlogUser)
                .OrderByDescending(p => p.Updated != null)
                .ThenByDescending(p => p.Updated)
                .ThenByDescending(p => p.Created)
                .ToListAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                //int readyStatusInt = (int)ReadyStatus.$"{readyStatus}";
                posts = await _context.Posts?
                //.Where(p => p.ReadyStatus == readyStatusInt)
                .Where(p => p.ReadyStatus.Equals(readyStatus))
                .Include(p => p.Blog)
                .Include(p => p.BlogUser)
                .OrderByDescending(p => p.Updated != null)
                .ThenByDescending(p => p.Updated)
                .ThenByDescending(p => p.Created)
                .ToListAsync();
            }

            ViewData["ReadyStatus"] = new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(ReadyStatus)).Cast<ReadyStatus>().ToList());
            return View(posts);
        }
```

View

```
    <form asp-action="IndexFilter" asp-controller="Posts">
        <div class="input-group  d-flex flex-md-row">
            @*<label class="form-label me-2">Filter by Category:</label>*@
            <select name="readyStatus" asp-items="@ViewBag.ReadyStatus" class="form-select w-50"
                    onchange="this.form.submit()" onfocus="this.selectedIndex=-1;">
                <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Filter By Status</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try  as below to convert the string you received to ReadyStatus :

```
ReadyStatus readyStatus = (ReadyStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(ReadyStatus), "PreviewReady");
```

Try

```
.Where(x => x.ReadyStatus== ReadyStatus.PreviewReady)
```

It works on myside now:

[image]

Comment: Thanks that got me closer. The readyStatusInt is now showing the correct index value. But now the posts show a count of 0. There must be something wrong with the where clause. I'm using PostgreSql, and in the Posts table the "ReadyStatus" column is of type int, so I am now comparing int to int. I'm not getting any errors, it's just the Where clause isn't finding the anything.

Comment: Sorry,the expression failed to be translated to Sql, I tried again and it works well on myside now,please check what I've updated

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks yet again for you help. this worked:  

```ReadyStatus readyStatusInt = (ReadyStatus)Enum.Parse(typeof(ReadyStatus), readyStatus);```

```.Where(p => p.ReadyStatus.Equals(readyStatusInt))```